# Execute mysql_query via e-mail

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm making a CMS for one of my friends. She is a writer with a looots of ideas and notes. I just realized that she needs a note taking webapp inside that CMS that allows her to make notes by simply writing an e-mail to a specific e-mail address. Like Evernote: the subject would be the 'title' of the note and the body would be the content.

But I cannot figure it out how to do that – in the past few days I was thinking only and nothing came out. I need a 'trigger' which runs a PHP script but how? Do you guys have some ideas?

I would really appreciate that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS is the email server on?

Comment: You'd probably need a cron job to run at some interval to check a mailbox, read and process the messages. Unfortunately this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Would be easier to make a simple web form that she could access from a smartphone or browser...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse emails in realtime as they are recieved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541278/how-do-i-parse-emails-in-realtime-as-they-are-recieved)

Comment: @Quentin: you are right, thanks a lot! It's just working (:

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an email address that "pipes" to an application, such as PHP.

If you are on a WHM server, cPanel accounts can easily do this. See: http://docs.whmcs.com/Email_Piping